# Is it possible to get the UDID with Sencha+ Phonegap on an IOS-inhouse app?

Tags: ios6, cordova, ios7, sencha-touch, udid

For example writing a plugin that helps getting it, as far as i saw its not possible going the device.uuid way from phonegap (i am using version 3) anymore.

I don't want to use the app on the appstore, no privacy concerns, it's an inhouse-app. I just need a unique identifier for ios 6 / ios7, so that i can define who is using the app and who isn't allowed and the udid seems to fit this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the device.uuid, but it isn't a real UUID

from phonegap doc

> iOS Quirk
>
> The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
> application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
> re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
> upgrade your app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
> reliable value.

I've created a plugin to get the identifier for vendor

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

> An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s
> vendor. (read-only)
>
> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
> app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
> changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
> device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can
> also when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app
> on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores
> the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle
> situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: Do you know if
"NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];" 
still functioning?

Comment: App doesn't compile if you use xcode 5, maybe with xcode 4, but the apple doc say it was removed on iOS 7